# Button text not appearing c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing a chess game program using windows forms (System.Windows.Forms) and I made a button to start a new game. For some reason the text that the button is supposed to display isn't showing at all. Other than that, the button functions perfectly well.

How Can I fix it?

Code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Chess.Properties;

public class Form1 : Form
{
    PictureBox[,] tiles = new PictureBox[8, 8];
    Button newGame = new Button();
    public Form1()
    {
        this.MinimumSize = new Size(560, 519);
        this.MaximumSize = new Size(560, 519);
        newGame.Click += new EventHandler(newGame_Click);
        newGame.Size = new Size(560, 519);
        newGame.Location = new Point(481, 0);
        newGame.Text = "New Game";
        newGame.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 24.0f, FontStyle.Bold);
        this.Controls.Add(newGame);
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
            {
                tiles[x, y] = new PictureBox();
                tiles[x, y].Size = new Size(60, 60);
                tiles[x, y].Location = new Point(x * 60, y * 60);
                tiles[x, y].Name = "";
                this.Controls.Add(tiles[x, y]);
                if (x == 0)
                    if (y % 2 == 0)
                        tiles[x, y].BackColor = Color.Gray;
                    else tiles[x, y].BackColor = Color.White;
                else if (tiles[x - 1, y].BackColor == Color.Gray)
                    tiles[x, y].BackColor = Color.White;
                else tiles[x, y].BackColor = Color.Gray;
            }
    }

    void newGame_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Initial White Pieces
        tiles[0, 0].Image = Resources.wTower;
        tiles[0, 1].Image = Resources.wHorse;
        tiles[0, 2].Image = Resources.wRunner;
        tiles[0, 3].Image = Resources.wQueen;
        tiles[0, 4].Image = Resources.wKing;
        tiles[0, 5].Image = Resources.wRunner;
        tiles[0, 6].Image = Resources.wHorse;
        tiles[0, 7].Image = Resources.wTower;
        tiles[0, 0].Name = "wTower";
        tiles[0, 1].Name = "wHorse";
        tiles[0, 2].Name = "wRunner";
        tiles[0, 3].Name = "wQueen";
        tiles[0, 4].Name = "wKing";
        tiles[0, 5].Name = "wRunner";
        tiles[0, 6].Name = "wHorse";
        tiles[0, 7].Name = "wTower";
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            tiles[1, i].Image = Resources.wSoldier;
            tiles[1, i].Name = "wSoldier";
        }
        //Initial Black Pieces
        tiles[7, 0].Image = Resources.bTower;
        tiles[7, 1].Image = Resources.bHorse;
        tiles[7, 2].Image = Resources.bRunner;
        tiles[7, 3].Image = Resources.bQueen;
        tiles[7, 4].Image = Resources.bKing;
        tiles[7, 5].Image = Resources.bRunner;
        tiles[7, 6].Image = Resources.bHorse;
        tiles[7, 7].Image = Resources.bTower;
        tiles[7, 0].Name = "bTower";
        tiles[7, 1].Name = "bHorse";
        tiles[7, 2].Name = "bRunner";
        tiles[7, 3].Name = "bQueen";
        tiles[7, 4].Name = "bKing";
        tiles[7, 5].Name = "bRunner";
        tiles[7, 6].Name = "bHorse";
        tiles[7, 7].Name = "bTower";
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            tiles[6, i].Image = Resources.bSoldier;
            tiles[6, i].Name = "bSoldier";
        }
    }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Resources:
[My resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEhU8.png)

Comment: this looks like hadnwritten Winforms. Did you look at what the form designer generates for a normal Button, maybe u miss some style settings

Comment: a normal button has this set `this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;`

Comment: you made a Button to "start a new game" but you making the Button a new game itself: Button newGame = new Button(); So when you run your program if you are seeing the board that is your button. You need to create a button and separately create your board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button is way to large and you are seeing just the left side portion of it , which excludes the part with the text. Try using this for your button size instead:

```
        newGame.Size = new Size(60, 519);
```